# Kali installation problem UUID

Tags: boot, kali-linux, fsck

I installed Kali on a partition and am trying to load it using gummiboot from a different partition.

Gummiboot finds linux and starts to load it. Startup then throws a series of errors about a partition uuid that doesn't exist.

```
fsck: couldn't find matching file system: PARTUUID=41afd7c4-....

-----------

Warning: File system check failed but did not detect errors
```

The UUID doesn't exist, I have checked using blkid.

So I have searched all the files in the installation and cannot find a single one that contains the string "41afd7c4" using grep.

```
grep -rnw '/mnt/' -e "41afd7c4"
```

Where is this uuid coming from?

Any input appreciated!

[image: error]